# Why doesn't "${0%/*}" work as expected on my machine?

Tags: windows, bash, unix, path

let's assume this is test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "file.sh" ]; then
    echo "File found!" # it will hit this line
else
    echo "File not found!"
fi

if [ -f "${0%/*}/file.sh" ]; then
    echo "File found!"
else
    echo "File not found!" # it will hit this line
fi
```

and file.sh exists in same folder next to test.sh
the output will be

```
+ '[' -f file.sh ']'
+ echo 'File found!'
File found!
+ '[' -f test.sh/file.sh ']'
+ echo 'File not found!'
File not found!
```

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure `folder` exists?

Comment: Where do you run that? In an interactive shell, `$0` is `-bash`. Try using `set -x` to see what your command expands to.

Comment: What is the context where you're using this? Is it interactive, or in a script, and if it's in a script how're you running it? What are you trying to accomplish by using `${0%/*}`?

Comment: the folder does exists

Comment: Well, what does `echo "${0%/*}/../folder"` print? Also debug your script with ex. `set -x` and see (and post) the output.

Comment: I updated my question, it only says no such file or directory

Comment: `${0/*}` is not `${0%/*}`. Please post the full message. The message is `bash: cd: <HERE is the directory you can inspect that is missing>: no such file or directory`. The error messages are verbose so you can get information from them. So what does `${0%/*}` expand to? what is the value of `$0`?

Comment: sorry modified it to ${0%/*}, still same error, also posted the error message, it should  be the script path but it's the script file name

Comment: What exactly did you expect?  Your script tests if file(s) exist.  The latter conditional is testing if a file exists (presumably) in a specific directory.  Which directory?   `$0` is equivalent to `argv[0]` which is the name of the script itself.   Did you intend to pass arguments to the script?  Did you intend to cause the script to `find` `file.sh`  ?

Comment: it should be the current path for the script, something like "." so it'd be "./file.sh" and that's how it works with my colleagues

Comment: @AhmedMohamed `$0` is generally the name used to run the script. This might be a full path, a relative path, or just a bare filename (if it's in `$PATH` or run with `sh` or `bash`), or... something else. Getting the location of the script is much more difficult; see [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are calling `test.sh`.

If you are calling it as `./test.sh` or `/path/to/test.sh`, then
`$0` will be `./test.sh` or `/path/to/test.sh` respectively and
`${0%/*}` will be `.` or `/path/to` respectively.

If you are calling it as `bash ./test.sh` or `bash /path/to/test.sh`, then
`$0` will be `./test.sh` or `/path/to/test.sh` respectively and
`${0%/*}` will be `.` or `/path/to` respectively.

Above cases would work.

However, if you are calling it as `cd /path/to; bash test.sh`, then `$0` will be `test.sh`.

`${0%/*}` will remove everything from `/`. Your `$0` does not have any `/`. So, it will remain unchanged. `${0%/*}` will equal `test.sh`.
Hence `${0%/*}/foo.sh` will be seen as non-existent.

Either you can use `dirname "$0"` or you can use below trivial logic:

```
mydir=${0%/*}
[ "$mydir" == "$0" ] && mydir=.
if [ -f "$mydir/file.sh" ]; then
#... whatever you want to do later...
```